# Cannot resolve symbols getIntent(), findViewById, etc

Tags: java, android

Cannot resolve symbol `findViewById()`, `getApplicationContext()`, and many more basic functions, maybe I did something wrong with the Resources file, but I don't know what to do now to correct.

```
package com.example.apple.onlinesql;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Answer extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView questionTextView, answerTextView;
String question, answer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    question = bundle.getString("question");
    answer = bundle.getString("answer");

    /*cannot resolve symbol findViewById()*/
    questionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionTextView);
    answerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);

    questionTextView.setText(question);
    answerTextView.setText(answer);

}
}
```

Comment: try to clean your project

Comment: Try choosing File | Invalidate Caches/Restart on the main menu..

Answer (score 1):

The application hasn't build successfully, as @vasilis mentioned try to clean and rebuild your project. And if that not solve the case, restart your studio and in worst case restart you system.

Comment: @Harshit if that's solve your problem, kindly accept it as answer.

Comment: No, It doesn't solve my problem either. Although I've noticed that the error disappears in other project.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be running into the corrupt cache bug in Android Studio.

To fix: File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 0):

I got the way although not very efficient but I got the way. I copied my entire project to a different location and opened it from there. MAGIC it worked for me.